# javascript variable key in loop

Tags: javascript, slickgrid

Using Slickgrid I am trying to set the CSS of a cell using setCellCssStyles method

```
for (var rowIndx = 1; rowIndx < movmentRows.length; rowIndx++) {
  grid.setCellCssStyles("disabled", {
    rowIndx: {
      san: "slick-cellreadonly",
      ean: "slick-cellreadonly",
    },
  });
}
```

I understand its because I am using a variable for a key in the for loop.
But I don't understand how to make this work. 
I tried to replace rowIndx with [rowIndx] but I am getting syntax error, so I think my JavaScript is not ES6. Then I tried the following but this is also giving syntax error with -

> Encountered '['and Expected keyword or brace.

```
for(var rowIndx=1;rowIndx<movmentRows.length;rowIndx++){
  var key = {};
  grid.setCellCssStyles("natCol-greyed", {
    key[rowIndx] : {
      sourceAccountNational: "slick-cellreadonly",
      excludeAccountNational: "slick-cellreadonly"
    }
  });
}
```

Please suggest.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating Dynamic Keys In Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53460072/creating-dynamic-keys-in-object)

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: You were close: `var key = {}; key[rowIndx] = { sourceAccountNational: "slick-cellreadonly", excludeAccountNational: "slick-cellreadonly" }; grid.setCellCssStyles("natCol-greyed", key);`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to add dynamically named properties to JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184123/is-it-possible-to-add-dynamically-named-properties-to-javascript-object)

Answer (score 0):

If movementRows is an array you can use a for...of loop like so:

```
for (const [index, row] of movmentRows.entries()) { //index is the index of each iteration and row is the value
  grid.setCellCssStyles("disabled", {
    [row]: {
      san: "slick-cellreadonly",
      ean: "slick-cellreadonly",
    },
  });
}
```

To set an object key as a variable you can put it in brackets..

Note on for..of loop: It is not supported in IE.

[More on how to dynamically set object properties](https://www.samanthaming.com/tidbits/37-dynamic-property-name-with-es6/)

[More on For...Of loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)

Comment: If the OP wants the index of the row as the key, this will not work; this will use the array element as the key.

Comment: I have updated my answer to support indexes as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to create an object but want to use a variable for the key, the syntax is as follows:

```js
let keyName = "foo"

let object = { [keyName]: "bar" }
 // gives the object `{"foo": "bar}
```

in older javascript you have to assign to a key after the object is created:

```js
let keyName = "foo"

let object = {}
object[keyName] = "bar"
```

Also, I try to never do a "manual" loop when I can use an iterator. It's less error prone than a "manual" loop, and allows you to use different types of collections other than just arrays, so it's more flexible. there are two main ways to do this:

A [`for … of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop:

```js
let collection = ["a", "b", "c"]

for (let value of collection) {
  console.log("value:", value)
}
// if you also want the index
for (let [index, value] of collection.entries()) {
  console.log("value and index:", value, index)
}
// or _just_ the indexes (note this skip empty values in sparse arrays)
for (let index of collection.keys()) {
  console.log("index:", index)
}
```

Using [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

```js
collection.forEach((item, index) => console.log(item, index))
```

Both these methods usually work about the same, but the `for … of` loop is closer to a "manual" loop. However, `forEach` is a bit older, so may be available more places. Also, take a look at the similar [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), for when you want to generate a new array for each item in the old one.

Comment: No, don't look at `map` unless you are using the output, which is another array. Also, the OP is using the index of the element in the array, so `for..of` doesn't even make sense. `forEach` would work if you included the `index` argument. But a plain `for` loop is fine

Comment: I mentioned `map` because I see so many people pushing to arrays instead of using map  :). But yes, for this specific case, `forEach` is better. But, also, check out `map` for future reference.

Comment: I see so many people using `map` for side effects instead of using `forEach` or a plain `for` loop :).

Comment: @HereticMonkey that bothers me less, honestly :). But usually I'm tying to remove side effects anyway, so `map` is what I want :).

Comment: @GarrettMotzner Do not encourage people to use `.map()` unless they want to manipulate the current iterating array. In this case for loop is just enough.

Comment: @BadPiggie Huh? Map exists to transform  each value of an array and collect them to a new array. AFAIK, if that's what you are doing, that's the way to do it. Why exactly do you think it is bad advice to use map? Just performance? I don't think that's a good enough reason, unless you need that much speed. Speed is less important than readability, maintainability, etc, up to a point. Absolutely, if you need to optimize for maximum performance and map is your biggest bottleneck left, don't use it. But I think it's a good practice to use it in general.

Answer (score 0):

People provide answers using different loops. But the loop isn't a problem here. Do not be ashamed of using the `for` loop. It is still the **best**.

[What's the fastest way to loop through an array in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5349425/whats-the-fastest-way-to-loop-through-an-array-in-javascript)

Let's get straight to the answer, You can do it without creating an additional `key` object. Your first workaround was almost correct, But since you want to use the `value` of `rowIndx` as the key, Just wrap it with `[]`.

```
  grid.setCellCssStyles("natCol-greyed", {
      [rowIndx]: {
          sourceAccountNational: "slick-cellreadonly",
          excludeAccountNational: "slick-cellreadonly"
      }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var rowIndx = 1; rowIndx < movmentRows.length; rowIndx++) {
  var styles = {};
  styles[rowIndx] = {
    san: "slick-cellreadonly",
    ean: "slick-cellreadonly",
  };

  grid.setCellCssStyles("disabled", styles);
}
```

You create an empty object (styles), and then you assign the dynamic key (rowIndx) with the corresponding styles.